# x-editable close on blur not working when I click on another x-editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I have a page with 2 x-editable text fields

```
<div class="edit name">
    <h3 class="name"><a editable-text="creator.name" e-class="input-md" blur="submit" onaftersave="updateField('name');">{{creator.name}}</a></h3>
</div>

<a editable-textarea="creator.bio" e-rows="4" e-cols="100%" onaftersave="updateField()" data-ng-show="editable" blur="submit" placeholder="Approximately a 100 word Bio">
    <span data-ng-bind="creator.bio"></span>
    <span data-ng-show="!creator.bio">Tell us about yourself in less than 100 words</span>
</a>
```

If I am editing one and I click anywhere on the page it updates and closes.
Except if I click on the other x-editable field. Then both stay open.
I want the first x-editable to save and close.

I have been able to reproduce this [in a plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/9463/). I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this happens when I am using version 0.1.9 if I go back to 0.1.8 works.

Bug is here [blur breaks on 0.1.9](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/303)

Answer (score 0):

just give one class in x-editable close button.
I think it works.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Where am I specifying more than one class?